# Using KNOWNFOLDERID or CSIDL in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, known-folders

Is there a way to use either [KNOWNFOLDERID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in PowerShell?

I need to be able to access some "known folders" via PowerShell script on a variety of systems. The problem is that those folders' names tend to differ between languages and Environmental Variables list (e.g. $env:something) does not contain folders I am interested accessing in (e.g. C:\Users).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the .NET method System.Environment.GetFolderPath like so:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::ApplicationData)
```

The [MSDN topic on the Environment.SpecialFolder enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) shows all the possible special folders you can ask for.

Comment: Same thing, different syntax: `[environment]::getfolderpath("ApplicationData")`. [Reference link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/20/the-easy-way-to-use-powershell-to-work-with-special-folders.aspx). +1

Comment: Sure but you don't get tab completion on the string version of the enum value.  :-)

Comment: Yep, but you can pass these via command line. Depending on what OP wants to do, it may be useful to know about both notations. :)

Comment: Absolutely good to know both ways.  I will use the string version when I know the enum value off the top of my head and the `[]::` version to tab complete when I don't know the enum values.

Comment: So I guess the short answer to my question would be "no"? Thanks for the work around with .net, though.

Comment: If the .NET workaround isn't good enough, you can try PInvoking out to SHGetFolderPath.  Have a look at the help for Add-Type.  There are some examples that show pinvoking to the Win32 API.